# Group Data in SQL on the base of Pair of Two Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, group-by

I have a SQL table for storing chat messages data in it. I am using `CreatedBy` column to identify that which user sent the chat message and `fk_MessageToUserID` store OD of the user whom message was sent. Below is the table structure.

[image: SQL table for storing chat data]

I am trying to list all users which are engaged in conversation with a specific user but unable to group the data properly. Below is the query which i have tried to build for this purpose.

```
SELECT
    MAX(cm.CreatedDate) AS LastMessageDateTime,
    SUM(CASE WHEN cm.IsRead = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 1 END) AS 'UnreadMessages',
    (CASE WHEN cm.CreatedBy = @userId THEN MAX(cm.fk_MesageToUserID) ELSE NULL END) AS fk_UserinfoID,
    (CASE WHEN cm.CreatedBy = @userId THEN (SELECT CONCAT(FirstName,' ',LastName) FROM UserInfo WHERE ID = MAX(cm.fk_MesageToUserID)) ELSE 'Test' END) AS fk_UserFullName,
    (SELECT TOP(1) MessageText FROM [dbo].[ChatMessages] 
     WHERE CreatedDate = MAX(cm.CreatedDate) ORDER BY ID DESC) AS LastMessage
FROM
    [dbo].[ChatMessages] AS cm
LEFT JOIN 
    UserInfo AS uc ON cm.CreatedBy = uc.ID
WHERE
    cm.CreatedBy = @userId OR cm.fk_MesageToUserID = @userId
GROUP BY
    cm.CreatedBy
```

For better understanding bellow is sample data and the desired output which I want to get.

[image]

If we run the query on above data set for the user "3d76ee09-772a-4697-9f10-08d8ae624465" then it should return the following result set as user with ID "3d76ee09-772a-4697-9f10-08d8ae624465" has conversation with only one user with the ID "B52F3DD2-2DBC-487C-9F0F-08D8AE624465" and only only message is unread.

```
LastMessageDateTime     | UnreadMessages  |  fk_UserInfoID                        | fk_UserFullName
------------------------+-----------------+---------------------------------------+-----------------
2021-01-13 14:15:41.353 |      2          | B52F3DD2-2DBC-487C-9F0F-08D8AE624465  | Demo Customer
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would clarify what you want,.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have updated the question with sample data and desired result set

Answer (score 1):

If i understand this correctly, you have an User, and you want all users with whom he conversed, either as sender or as recipient.

easiest way would be to split to two queries, one for sender, one for recipient
ie:

```
;with cteTable as (
SELECT
        MAX(cm.CreatedDate) AS LastMessageDateTime,
        SUM(CASE When cm.IsRead = 0 THEN 0 Else 1 END) AS 'UnreadMessages'
    FROM
        mess AS cm
    WHERE
        cm.CreatedBy = @userId
    GROUP BY
       cm.CreatedBy
union all
SELECT
        MAX(cm.CreatedDate) AS LastMessageDateTime,
        SUM(CASE When cm.IsRead = 0 THEN 0 Else 1 END) AS 'UnreadMessages'
    FROM
        mess AS cm
    WHERE
        cm.fk_MesageToUserID = @userId
    GROUP BY
       cm.fk_MesageToUserID)
select max(LastMessageDateTime) as LastMessageDateTime,
       sum(UnreadMessages) as UnreadMessages from cteTable
```